# How can I distinguish between an official or unofficial patch?

Tags: championship-manager-season-97-98

I recently dug out my CD for Championship Manager: Season 97/98 but I am missing the official patch (version 2.93).

The patch was originally available from the game developer but they have since split from the original franchise (i.e. now developing Football Manager).  I cannot see the patch on their website.

I have checked several websites but have encountered one of these problems:

1. When finding links to download the 2.93 patch from historic fan sites the patch is no longer available (no sure way of downloading the patch as it was)
2. Obscure "CM2 97/97" patches are turning up as unofficial update for teams/players mainly regarding approximately the 2011/12 season (this will vary depending on the site)
3. Several abandonware sites are giving me copies of the full game complete with additional editors/tools etc - and I cannot confirm whether this is a patched copy of the game

What I want is the official 2.93 patch, which I believe was a zip file or an exe named something like "patchzip".  The file was pretty small, maybe less than 10MB.  It patches the CM exe file, possibly the editor, and updates around 3 game data files.

In the absence of an explicit download to the official patch/update is there a sure-fire way of determining if an installation has:

1. been patched with the official update?
2. not seen any custom edits (new players added beyond the "vanilla" update?

Specifically - anything in-game or examination of game files (readme's, timestamps etc).

Comment: You got an answer, if you found it, can you post it?

Comment: @ardaozkal - http://www.patches-scrolls.com/dl.php?file=cm98_upd.zip

Comment: While Microsoft Onedrive is alive, this patch is alive too: http://1drv.ms/1EtV3Wh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last (maybe only) official patch was v2.93.

In order to tell if the patch is installed you can check for the following:

**Look for a patch zip or folder**

If it exists, it will contain the following files:

1. CHANGES.DOC
2. CHANGES.TXT
3. EIDOS.PCX
4. ENG_MTCH.TXT
5. HISCORES.BIN
6. mgdata.db1
7. PATCHZIP.EXE
8. players.db1
9. PLHIST98.BIN
10. READTHIS.TXT
11. TMDATA.DB1

**The game has post-patch features**

Check international squads on match day when playing a friendly - any player that has a club match on the same day will be "club-tied" and therefore unable to play (Wales and Ireland are good candidates for checking).

This should be the second screen you see when loading the game:

[image: Eidos Screen]

The main options screen will show v2.93 in the top left hand corner:

[image: Menu Screen]

**Check database file properties**

The key files are:

1. mgdata.db1 - 12th March 1998
2. players.db1 - 12th March 1998
3. TMDATA.DB1 - 11th March 1998

You will need to check the timestamps in the archive (zip file for example) because copying the files directly to your machine will give the files a new timestamp.

**Check the editor**

Load each database and check the record count in the top left corner:

1. MGDATA - 944 records
2. PLAYERS - 19505 records
3. TMDATA.DB1 - 2085 records

**Check key teams in-game**

You need a little football knowledge for this.  Check England and some key Premier League teams (Man Utd, Chelsea, Man City, Liverpool, Arsenal).  If they are filled with anything but 1997/98 players then you know you have unofficial amendments.